# Dynamic Livewire Listeners : Listener does not listen for triggered event

Tags: laravel, listener, event-listener, laravel-livewire, livewires

I'm having trouble with dynamic Livewire listeners. I'm trying to use two components on the same page, where one component has an input field and the other is a modal that is supposed to fire an event on the second input component when a button is clicked.

Here is my first component, Input:

```
class Input extends Component {
 public $name; public $type; public $multiple; public $selectedMedias; public $previewFiles;
public $listeners = [];


public function mount($name, $type, $multiple, $selectedMedias = '')
{
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->type = $type;
    $this->multiple = $multiple;

    if ($selectedMedias) {
        $this->selectedMedias = explode(',', $selectedMedias);
        $this->previewFiles = $this->getFileData($this->selectedMedias);
    }

    $this->listeners = ['updateSelectedMedias:'.$this->name => 'updateSelectedMedias'];
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.dashboard.medias.input');
}

public function updateSelectedMedias($selectedMedias)
{
    $this->selectedMedias = $selectedMedias;
    $this->previewFiles = $this->getFileData($this->selectedMedias);
    $this->emit('hideModal');
}

private function getFileData($ids)
{
    $medias = Media::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();

    $data = $medias->map(function ($item) {
        return [
            'id' => $item->id,
            'url' =>  $item->getUrl(),
            'name' => $item->file_name,
        ];
    });

    return $data->toArray();
}}
```

Here is my second component, the modal, which is supposed to fire an event on the second input component:

```
class Modal extends Component { public $name; public $selectedMedias;
public function mount($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}

public function addMedias()
{
    $this->emitUp('updateSelectedMedias:'.$this->name, $this->selectedMedias);
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.dashboard.medias.modal');
}
```

The event is fired on the first input component but not on the second input component on the same page. Here is the Livewire Blade template code:

```
`<livewire:dashboard.medias.input name="images" type="image" multiple="true" selected-medias="1,2" />

<livewire:dashboard.medias.input name="images2" type="image" multiple="true" selected-medias="5" />`
```

even if i'm getting the correct response from the second component !

**response: { event: "updateSelectedMedias:images2", params: [["5"]], ancestorsOnly: true }**

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution :

Instead of using dynamic listeners, I just add an extra parameter to the emit function to pass the name and check it in the other component. In the modal component, modify the addMedias function like this:

```
public function addMedias()
{
    $this->emit('updateSelectedMedias', $this->name, $this->selectedMedias);
}
```

in the Input component :

```
protected $listeners = ['updateSelectedMedias'];


public function updateSelectedMedias($inputname, $selectedMedias)
{
    if ($inputname == $this->name) {
        $this->selectedMedias = $selectedMedias;
        $this->previewFiles = $this->getFileData($this->selectedMedias);
        $this->emit('hideModal');
    }
}
```